# Java file name filter to match a search interval

Tags: java, file

I tried to find the answer to my problem in the questions history but can't find. So here is my problem.

Lets imagine that a have a directory structure like this:

```
project
| -- 20150201
| -- 20150202
|   | -- 1423500700241.xml
|   | -- 1423500720009.xml
|   | -- 1423500760005.xml
| -- 20150203
|   | -- 1423500780006.xml
|   | -- 1423500800006.xml    
| -- 20150204
|   | -- 1423500820005.xml
|   | -- 1423500840008.xml    
| -- report
```

what I want is that from a date period selected by a user i process the files inside the directory;

Example:

When a user search for 20150201 to 20150203 i need to process the files inside the directories.

I did this so far:

```
public class FileFilterDateIntervalUtil implements Serializable, FilenameFilter {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 226591338838691089L;

    private static final SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

    private String initialDate;
    private String endingDate;

    public FileFilterDateIntervalUtil(String initialDate, String endingDate) {
        this.initialDate = initialDate;
        this.endingDate = endingDate;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        String currentDate = DATE_FORMAT.format(new Date(new File(dir, name).lastModified()));

        return ( (this.initialDate.compareTo(currentDate) < 0) && (this.endingDate.compareTo(currentDate) >= 0) );
    }
}
```

but when i did this i search for the last modifieds files, and this is not what i want, i want to search by the directories names by a date interval.

Someone can help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the way you have implemented the accept method. Instead of using a directory's last modified date and the current date, you should be using a directory's name alone to achieve your objective.

```
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            Date dirDate = null;
            try {
                dirDate = DATE_FORMAT.parse(name.trim());
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Cannot parse date "+name+" reason "+e.getMessage());
                return false;
            }

            String dirDateStr = DATE_FORMAT.format(dirDate);

            return initialDate.compareTo(dirDateStr) * dirDateStr.compareTo(endingDate) > 0;
        }
```

The above accept method can be used to get the list of all the files that fall between the initial and ending date (excluding the initial and ending date).

Comment: The problem is that i have 'report' folder inside my folder structure, that throws java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "report".

Comment: That won't happen if you add a try catch like I have done in my answer. Also, that was not the only problem with your code. You also used last modified instead of using the actual dir name in the accept method.

Comment: The report folder will be skipped. Only folders for which the name can be parsed into a valid date and those that satisfy the date interval will be returned. You can then iterate through the folders that you got as a result of the filtering and read the files within them one by one. Let me know if you need any more clarifications. If this worked for you, do upvote and mark the answer as accepted.